# The def boo(list_products) doesn´t work as it should, any hint to make it works

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a list:

```
["seccion", 
    "product A", 
    "product B", 
    "product C", 
"seccion", 
    "product D", 
    "product E", 
"seccion", 
    "product F",
    "product G",
    "product H",
    "product I"]
```

and try to build a function which print:

```
"seccion"
"product A, product B, product C"
"seccion"
"product D, product E"
"seccion"
"product F, product G, product H, product I"
```

The list can change, there can be more sections or products

```
def boo(list_products):
    list_index_seccion = []
    index = 0
    for line in list_products:
        if line == 'seccion':
            list_index_seccion.append(index)
        index += 1
    #print(list_index_seccion) # [0, 4, 7]
    index = 0
    for line in list_products:
        string = ""
        if line == 'seccion':
            print(line)

            seccion_nr_sub = 0
            for line in list_products:
                if line == 'seccion': 
                    seccion_nr_sub += 1 
                if seccion_nr_sub == 2:
                   break                    
                if line != 'seccion':
                    string += line + ", "

        print(string)
        index +=1
```

Any one could help how to improve this code to give the correct result? Would be greateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for the task:

```
lst = ["seccion",
    "product A",
    "product B",
    "product C",
"seccion",
    "product D",
    "product E",
"seccion",
    "product F",
    "product G",
    "product H",
    "product I"]

from itertools import groupby

for _, g in groupby(lst, lambda k: k=='seccion'):
    print(', '.join(g))
```

Prints:

```
seccion
product A, product B, product C
seccion
product D, product E
seccion
product F, product G, product H, product I
```